# How can I create a database with utf8mb4 characterset from spring with CreateDatabaseIfNotExist?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mariadb

In my Spring `application.properties`, I set the datasource to a MariaDB via JBDC.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbname?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

It successfully creates the MariaDB database. However, the `characterset` and `connectioncollation` is set to `latin1`.

Is there a way to create `utf8mb4` databases with `createDatabaseIfNotExist`. If not, is there a different method to create a database where I can specify `utf8mb4` as the `characterset` and `connectionsollation` programmatically?
[picture of the databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfKhA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below string:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/somedbname123?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Has anyone verified this?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly still the same. :( I added a picture after I added your requested line.